# API on Rust, error: "data limit exceeded"

Tags: rust, serde-json, rocket

I need to make an API on Rust, to which you give a string, it performs some function, and then returns a new string. But an error occurred, if the string is too long, then an error occurs:

```
POST /test:
   >> Matched: (test) POST /test
   >> Data guard `String` failed: Custom { kind: UnexpectedEof, error: "data limit exceeded" }.
   >> Outcome: Failure
   >> No. 400 catcher registered. Using Rocket default.
   >> Response succeeded.
```

rust code:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;
#[macro_use] extern crate serde_json;

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> String {
    json!({"message": "Hello, world!"}).to_string()
}

#[post("/test", data = "<data>")]
fn test(data: String) -> String {
    json!({"data": data}).to_string()
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes![index, test])
}
```

cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.5.0-rc.3"
serde_json = "1.0.64"
rocket_sync_db_pools = "0.1.0-rc.3"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
rocket_contrib = "0.4.11"
```

I tried to solve the problem with ChatGPT and perplexity ai but they didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure limits based on the incoming data type in your rocket.toml like so:

```ini
[default.limits]
form = "64 kB"
json = "1 MiB"
msgpack = "2 MiB"
"file/jpg" = "5 MiB"
```

See [Configuration](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/configuration/#configuration) in the Rocket Programming Guide for more. Here's also the [built-in limits](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/data/struct.Limits.html#built-in-limits).

---

In your case, you are using `String`, which will map to the `"string"` limit which is 8KiB by default. Curious that you aren't using the [`Json`](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/serde/json/struct.Json.html) type, which would handle serializing and deserializing for you in addition to having a higher limit by default, but to each their own.

So you would do something like this (higher or lower as you prefer):

```ini
[default.limits]
string = "1 MiB"
```

Comment: I couldn't find the rocket.toml file. Should I create it?

Comment: @DuxtaEgor yes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket/config/struct.Limits.html , if you are posting huge json string (>32KiB by rocket default setting).

To increase the body size limit, change `fn rocket()` to

```rust
use rocket::{
    config::{Environment, Limits},
    Config,
};

fn main() {
    let conf = Config::build(Environment::Development)
        .limits(Limits::new().limit("forms", 1048576 * 1024))
        .unwrap();

    rocket::custom(conf)
        .mount(...)
        .launch();
}
```